# How would I do a custom pandas dataframe merge?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have:

```
data = [['tom', 10, 20], ['nick', 15, 30], ['juli', 14, 40]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Low-Age', 'High-Age']) 
print(df)
None
   Name  Low-Age  High-Age
0   tom       10        20
1  nick       15        30
2  juli       14        40
```

And then I have another table:

```
data = [[10, 'school'], [30, 'college']] 
edu = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Age', 'Education']) 
print(edu)
None
   Age Education
0   10    school
1   30   college
```

How would I get a table where I would match edu['Age'] against either the df["Low-Age"] or df["High-Age"]. If they match I would like to append edu["Education"] to df. (assume either low-age or high-age could have a match, NOT both)

So I would expect my output to be:

```
  Name  Low-Age  High-Age   Education
0   tom       10        20    school
1  nick       15        30    college
2  juli       14        40     NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use map with combine_first

```
mapper = edu.set_index('Age')['Education']
df['Education'] = df['Low-Age'].map(mapper).combine_first(df['High-Age'].map(mapper))

    Name    Low-Age High-Age    Education
0   tom     10      20          school
1   nick    15      30          college
2   juli    14      40          NaN
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out:
`pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` -> This error will pop up if `Age` values in df `edu` are not unique.

Answer (score 4):

#### `stack` -> `map`

```
edu_dict = dict(zip(edu.Age, edu.Education))

Education = df[['Low-Age', 'High-Age']].stack().map(edu_dict).groupby(level=0).first()
df.assign(Education=Education)

   Name  Low-Age  High-Age Education
0   tom       10        20    school
1  nick       15        30   college
2  juli       14        40       NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) + [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
edu2=edu.set_index('Age')
s=pd.concat([df['Low-Age'].map(edu2['Education']),df['High-Age'].map(edu2['Education'])])
df['Education']=s[s.notna()].reindex(index=df.index)
print(df)

   Name  Low-Age  High-Age Education
0   tom       10        20    school
1  nick       15        30   college
2  juli       14        40       NaN
```

Also you can sum instead [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
edu2=edu.set_index('Age')
df['Education']= ( df['High-Age'].map(edu2['Education']).fillna('')+
                  df['Low-Age'].map(edu2['Education']).fillna('') )
```

or

```
edu2=edu.set_index('Age')
df['Education']= df[['High-Age','Low-Age']].apply(lambda x: x.map(edu2['Education']).fillna('')).sum(axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df)

   Name  Low-Age  High-Age Education
0   tom       10        20    school
1  nick       15        30   college
2  juli       14        40
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach gets you results in less time when working with large datasets. apply() is used.

```
low_age_list = df['Low-Age'].tolist()
high_age_list = df['High-Age'].tolist()

def match(row):
   print(row[1])
      if row['Age'] in low_age_list or row['Age'] in high_age_list:
         return row[1]

df['Education'] = edu.apply(match,axis=1)
print(df)
```